# How to offset an animation of a linked collection? (linked from another blend file)

Tags: animation, linked-data, collections

I have two files, the first is the render scene with a building, the second contains a scaled up animation of a drilling process with particles and smoke. I can link that animation as a collection, scale it down, rotate and move. And seems all physics and animations work. But I can't find a way to shift the start point of that animation.
My render scene starts from 1000 and the drilling animation starts from frame 1. I was hoping to reuse that animation several times in the same scene without rebaking and additional tuning. Is it even possible?

Comment: I think this is a missing feature in Blender. I'd be very interested in seeing this implemented.

Comment: @unfa, there is a submitted proposal on [rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/9Sfbbc/). It's not very popular, probably there is a better articulated post.

Comment: Thanks for linking this proposal, I've supported it and shared my thoughts.
This feels like a very basic feature honestly...